# OAuth2 & Node.js - No redirect after Google confirmation

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I'm using Node.js to authenticate my web application with Google+. I've followed the official instructions [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client). My code looks like this:

```
var google = require('googleapis');

// OAuth
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var plus = google.plus('v1');
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
    'MY_CLIENT_ID', // Client id
    'MY_CLIENT_SECRET', // Client secret
    'http://localhost:8080/oauth' // Redirect url
);

function getOAuthUrl(){
    var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'
    });

    return url;
}

// OAuth authorization
app.use('/oauth', function(req, res){
    var session = req.session;
    var code = req.query.code;

    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, tokens) {
        // Now tokens contains an access_token and an optional refresh_token. Save them.
        if (!err) {
            oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
            session['tokens'] = tokens;
            res.redirect(__dirname + '/public/html/redirect.html?r=1'); // Success!
        }else{
            res.redirect(__dirname + '/public/html/redirect.html?r=0'); // Fail!
        }
    });
});
```

The login page is called `index.html` at the root of my folder. The login page makes an ajax request to `/oauth/url` which responds with the OAuth2 url that the user must click.

JS on `index.html`:

```
/* OAuth */
$.ajax({
    url: '/oauth/url',
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    success: function (e) {
        $('#login').attr('href', e);
    }
});
```

Node.js response:

```
// Get OAuth URL
app.use('/oauth/url', function(req, res){
    var url = getOAuthUrl();
    res.end(url);
});
```

I can click the link to take me to the authentication page as normal. But when I select the account to authenticate, the page freezes and doesn't get redirected to `localhost:8080/oauth` like it's supposed to.

**UPDATE:**
Looking at the networking tab on the console I noticed that the `GET` request to the callback is being cancelled. The code is recieved by Node.js and so is the request.

[image: The console network log]

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point in `/oauth` or even the `getToken` callback? Seems like an obvious place to start.

Comment: Well I hadn't, thanks for pointing that out. It turns out a request was being made. I placed a `console.log` every step of the way and everything seems to work fine. So why isn't the page redirecting to `redirect.html`?

Comment: I'd start from tracing http requests from the browser. There are quite a few redirects required to authenticate user with oauth2

Comment: @Lolechi do you have a static route setup? `/public/html/` in the redirect URL looks pretty suspect to me.

Comment: @James Yes, but somehow I cannot access static files without first putting `/public/`. Here is the line: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`. I never got around to fixing that, now might be a good time.

Comment: @Lolechi based on your static route, your redirect URL is `/html/redirect.html`

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

The issue was with the static directory not allowing Node.js to redirect the page. Fixed by changing the redirect address to `/html/redirect.html`. Thank you [@James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82586/james).